# jquerymobile need refresh first when need take the effect from another js

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

the case is like this ,
I have `<a>` tag

```html
a href="page2.html"
```

When I click and then go to page2.htm ,
the effect from another js dont appears,

If I manual refresh like press f5 from browser the effect appears

I add another function for `<a>`

```js
function refreshPage() {

    $.mobile.changePage(
       url,
      {
          allowSamePageTransition : true,
          transition : 'none',
          showLoadMsg : false,
          reloadPage : true
      }
   );
}
```

so tag `<a>` become :

```html
a href="page2.html" onClick="refreshPage()"
```

but the problem not solved
why ?
sorry, my english is not good
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

disable default link behavior:

```
<a href="page2.html" onClick="refreshPage()" data-ajax="false">foo</a>
```